# MySQL Create a table with two others and adding record with C# WinForms

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Question 1:

I have a big problem, now I'm building WinForm Application, I have two tables:

**Table1 clients** (  clientID, name, surname, pesel  )
**Table2 cars** (  carID, carBrand, carModel, registrationNumber  )

I'm trying to make **table3 parkingSpot** with:

```
( spotID,
 name  (values from clients->name),
 surname  (values from clients->surname),
 pesel  (values from clients->pesel),
 registrationNumber  (values from cars->registrationNumber),
 days)
```

How to do it?

Question 2:

Let's say that I have this table, now I want to make Form where I can add record to table **parkingSpot**  [Form Add Reserv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVGti.jpg)
I know how to bind data from a database to comboBoxes but I don't know how to make Add reservation button, how to get values from comboBoxes, textBox and get it to make a new record in the parkingSpot table.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:

You don't need to add `name`, `surname` etc columns in the third table. It can just be a mapping table like this:

```
id INT,
client_id INT,
car_id INT
```

`client_id` and `car_id` can be foreign keys for `client` and `car` tables respectively.

Answer 2:

Once user selects the values from combo-box, you can write an `INSERT` query and supply ids of `client` and `car` to create a new row.

Also, to get the rows back, you can use `JOIN`, [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) is the documentation and examples for `JOIN`.